# Warning: require(__DIR__/cherry-framework/setup.php

Tags: php, wordpress

Can't install wordpress the error after entering domain. the hosting PHP version is 5

> Warning: require(**DIR**/cherry-framework/setup.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/content/a/s/c/asclaw/html/wp-content/plugins/power-builder/tm-builder-core.php on line 42
>
> Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required '**DIR**/cherry-framework/setup.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/php5/lib/php') in /home/content/a/s/c/asclaw/html/wp-content/plugins/power-builder/tm-builder-core.php on line 42

Comment: Looks like your setup.php file is missing

Comment: where should it be?

Answer (score 0):

download CherryFramework. Extract cherry-plugin.zip files to wp-content/plugins/cherry-plugin directory replacing existing files. This should fix the issue.

Comment: there is no cherry-plugin directory

Comment: create that directory in here : /home/content/a/s/c/asclaw/html/wp-content/plugins/
 and extract the plugins (CherryFramework ) content there.

DIR indicates the constant i guess it's either
/home/content/a/s/c/asclaw/html/wp-content/plugins/
or
/home/content/a/s/c/asclaw/html/wp-content/plugins/power-builder/

try to extract the plugin in both location ( If above method not work).

Comment: I have cherry-data-importer, cherry-services-list, cherry-sidebars, cherry-team-members, and cherry-testi on my plugin directory

Comment: That's why you are getting the error. the framework plugin is missing there. you need that plugin.

Comment: I've download cherry framework, and now uploading to plugin directory, hope it'll help.

Comment: could it be of hosting PHP version?

Comment: no, it's because of missing the required plugin. the plugin must be place in the directory so that the power builder can access the setup file on this location DIR/cherry-framework/setup.php

but as i do not code the plugin i cant say what is defined by DIR/ here. it is a constant. i recommend you to contact with the developer or hire someone who can practically works to identify the absolute location.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  I discovered the site was running on PHP 5.3 even though their cpanel showed the server was running 5.4.

I added the following to the .htaccess and it got the site working:
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php

Check you PHP version, I'm sure that's the issue.